# Python + Curl - how to fix "Empty reply from server"

Tags: python, curl

I use https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997 python code to setup a http server.
For my use I just add few lines to the 'do_POST' method:

```
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("POST!")
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        print(content_length )
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        print(post_data)
```

I want to send a file through Curl :

```
curl -F "file=@file.txt" "http://myServer.noip.me:22222/" --trace-ascii debugdump.txt
```

Client side : Curl response is:

```
 curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Server side : server prints content_length value and then completely hangs at line "self.rfile.read(content_length)". It does not print 'print(post_data)'.

Firewall has been disabled on both side.

Last lines from debugdump.txt (Client side):

```
== Info: Empty reply from server
== Info: Connection #0 to host myServer.noip.me left intact
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Add `-X POST` to your `curl` command

Comment: Same error message with -X POST.

Comment: @rdas see also [curl author's blog post](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/) on why your suggestion to use `-X` is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

With Python's [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) package it's your responsibility to explicitly send an HTTP status code as part of your `do_POST()` override.

In your example code you first reply to the client (i.e. via [send_header()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.send_header), [end_headers()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers) and [wfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.wfile) *before* reading the whole POST request from the client!

See also Python's `wfile` documentation:

> Contains the output stream for writing a response back to the client. Proper adherence to the HTTP protocol must be used when writing to this stream in order to achieve successful interoperation with HTTP clients.

So this looks racy and you probably just need to make sure that you read the complete POST request **before** you start replying.

---

IOW, curl just complains that it didn't receive any HTTP status code from your server before the connection was closed. Apparently the connection isn't properly shutdown on both sides such that your server blocks on the read side.

That curl error

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

would also show up if you simply forget to send a status code by omitting

```
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
```

at the end of your method - or if your method prematurely exits (e.g. because it raises an exception).

However, the latter issues should show up in stderr ouput of your server.

Answer (score 0):

`Empty reply from server` means that the server closed the connection without responding *anything* which is a HTTP protocol violation.

This should never happen with a proper server so it signals something is seriously wrong in the server side.

Sometimes this happens because the server was naively implemented and crashes or misbehaves on an unexpected request coming from a client. The best chance to make this work then, is to try to alter the request in ways to make it more similar to the way the badly written server software might expect it to be.

This is a matter of guessing. Something is wrong in that server of yours.

Comment: Downvoted because the OP clearly wrote the server using Python's `http.server` module. The problem their having is a problem with the `http.server` library that they used.

Comment: Your answer awefuly sounds like you think the OP is writing the client: "... try to alter the request..." and "...contact the server administrators" (which was in the first revision when I commented). After editing, the answer is still not helpfully addresses anything about the Python server code.

Comment: Looking at OP's code his server effectively replies with an HTTP status code and body before reading the POST request body from the client. I'm not sure if this is even allowed by the HTTP standard.